# Alarming Rate of "Sign-Out Errors" in Outlook Account

Tags: privacy, email, outlook

After I logout from my Outlook account, I get high frequency of "signing out error" reports, with the following message:

> Hmm... we're having trouble signing you out. You may still be signed in to some applications. Close your browser to finish signing out. Or, head back to outlook.com.

My question, whether this problem could be an indication that someone else in signed into the account?

Comment: Better ask Outlook.com support directly. It's quite curious that there are websites that you cannot signed out from...

Comment: As a quick solution you could clear your web browser's "cookies and cache" it's possible a JS file went corrupt in transit or a cookie's session went haywire. I'm still curious about why you are having the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I log-in to the account from a single device. That's why it's puzzling why I can't log-out correctly. Inability to log-out, could mean (theoretically) that someone else simultaneously connects the account from another device, or exploit still ongoing traffic to the account to gain access to it later on. Either way, it's highly underestimated vulnerability of many email providers. If the problem persists, I will contact outlook support team.

Comment: I think Outlook generally works in the background when you're not there... that would mean the JWT could be set with "offline_access". I think the standard logout flow of OpenID would not revoke the token if that's set. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=http#authorization-request

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error but only under one condition. I am pointing users to a  URL which skips home realm discovery:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&whr=**domain.name**`

Signing in works perfectly, and after this I'm redirected to the Office Portal, but when I press “Sign Out” on the Office Portal, I get a “Hmm… we’re having trouble signing you out.” error.
This is something to do with the fact that the above URL creates a WS-FED session and Office Portal is then generates an OpenID Connect session. Sign Out requests an OIDC sign-out and interestingly enough also a WS-FED sign-out session with a `wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0` parameter, but something most likely does not detect the end of the WS-Fed session, hence the error.